# manually splitting a string in python - issue with the last delimiter

Tags: python

I wrote this:

```
def split(line,delim):
    s=[]
    j=0
    for i in range (len(line)-1):
        if delim== line [i]:
            s.append(line[j:i])
            j=i+1
    s.append (line[j:])
    return s
```

but when I put a `line` and the `end-letter` as the delim, it return also the delim like this:

```
split('bndghsjhskashakhs', 's')

['bndgh', 'jh', 'ka', 'hakhs']
```

Comment: Be more specific in your question ("i need help (in python)…" means nothing".  Also, explain what is wrong. You want to have 's' appended to all parts or you want to remove the 's' from the last part. Also, is this homework ?

Comment: You could remove the last letter of the element.  It's a quick-and-dirty fix though...

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in your:

```
for i in range (len(line)-1):
```

This iterates from the first character to the before-last character. It ignores the last character. Change it to:

```
for i in range (len(line)):
```

Now it returns `['bndgh', 'jh', 'ka', 'hakh', '']`.

Anyway, as the other posters write, you could use the standard `.split()` function.

If you want to remove the empty elements, you can include a filter at the end:

```
return [ item for item in s if item ]
```

instead of

```
return s
```

or directly with the standard split without your function:

```
[ item for item in line.split('s') if item ]
```

or the shortest version:

```
filter(None, line.split('s'))
```

Comment: @t.a. - `item` is a variable that is used only in that one line of  list comprehension, so you can change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

you should use native split rather than rewriting your own:
   `'bndghsjhskashakhs'.split('s')`

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should use the inbuild `string.split('s')` for something like this, it'll save any trouble.

The reason you're missing the last character is because of the:

```
for i in range (len(line)-1):
```

`range` will return 0..max-1, so you're actually stopping a character early.

Remove the -1 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
>>> 'bndghsjhskashakhs'.split('s')
['bndgh', 'jh', 'ka', 'hakh', '']
```

Or if you don't want empty values:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x, 'bndghsjhskashakhs'.split('s'))
['bndgh', 'jh', 'ka', 'hakh']
```

Comment: Try to replace `lambda x: x` with `None` and see what happens.

Comment: @eumiro, sure. Try `import this`. On the one hand "Explicit is better than implicit": `filter(lambda x: x,)`. On the other hand "Simple is better than complex": `filter(None,)`. On the gripping hand "There should be one obvious way to do it": FAIL. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hi I have a way for you.**.. 
Have done this without a single use of inbuilt split function

```
def split_string(string,divider):
  parts = []
  last = ""
  reverse = string[::-1]
  for i in string:
      if i == divider:
          parts.append(last)
          last = ""
      else:
          last = last + i
  reverse = reverse + string[0]
  first = ""
  for x in reverse:
          if x != divider:
              first = first + x
          else:
              break
  parts.append((first[::-1]))
  return (parts)
```

*Now just print this*

```
print(split_string("bndghsjhskashakhs","s"))
```